# Concating the string to another string

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to create a tag like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` on button click, so i have created a simple function to achieve this

```
function onclick(){
    var element = getStringBuilder();
    element.append("<?xml version=" + "1.0" + " encoding=" + "UTF-8" + " standalone=" + "no" + "?>");
    element = element.toString();
}

  function getStringBuilder () {

             var data = [];
             var counter = 0;

             return {
                 // adds string s to the stringbuilder

                 append: function (s) {
                     data[counter++] = s;
                     return this;
                 },
                toString: function (s) { return data.join(s || ""); }
        }
    }
```

But i am getting output as below

`<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 standalone=no?>`, i want "1.0", "UTF-8", "no" as string in the tag. How can i achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

What you're currently doing doesn't have any quotation marks within the string. `"a" + "b"` concatenates the strings containing the characters `a` and `b` together to make `"ab"`, *not* `"a""b"`.

The easiest way to do this is to wrap your entire string in single quotes (`'`) and retain the double quotes (`"`) within your string:

```
element.append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>');
```

Another method is to *escape* your double quotes to make JavaScript treat them as part of the string:

```
element.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

By actually including them in the string?

```
element.append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, just use different quotes:

```
element.append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>');
```

In the more general case, escape:

```
element.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>");
```

Either way, concatenating is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses " to separate the strings. Use ' and inside this, use ". Like this:

```
element.append('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>');
```